# Who made this grandfather clock?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, technology

I found this grandfather clock and I was fascinated by its workings. Since this is about history, I'd like to know who made it so I can research the rest. I will upload four pictures of it.

First picture:

[image: First picture]

Second picture:

[image: Second picture]

Third picture:

[image: Third picture]

Fourth picture:

[image: Fourth picture]

Comment: I tried doing an IMG src, but I didn't see any graphics, nor did my screen reader, for I am blind, announce that there were any graphics, so I added some normal external links to my web server where I've uploaded them.

Comment: I've moved the pictures into the question body. Hope that's OK.

Comment: How did you add the pictures? When I pressed control G it brought up a little box where I could upload the picture or use an external link. However, the images were greater than 2 MB, so I wasn't able to upload them. When I saw the edit, I saw the exclamation point, followed by two square bracket sets. In the first one, there was a description, and in the second block, there was a number from 1 to 4.

Comment: I just downloaded the pics and reduced the image sizes to under the 2MB limit before loading them into the question. :)

Comment: And how did you reduce the image? Thanks.

Comment: I just used an image editor on my PC. Most graphics programs will allow you to resize the image. :)

Comment: There are command line tools which *may* be easier for visually impaired folk to use. E.g. [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink) and some of the [NetPBM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pamscale.html) suite of tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dial is marked Howard Miller, who are still around and have their own [web site](http://www.howardmiller.com/clocks).

Your clock looks very similar to the [611-252 Celine](http://www.howardmiller.com/ProductDisplay?catalogId=13551&storeId=12652&productId=6410252&langId=-1&categoryId=&parent_category_rn=&top_category=) in their current catalogue, so might be an earlier model:

[image: Model Celine]